# Event handlers are ignored. Backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

There's a *view* defined in my project:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'eventbus', 'text!templates/traveller.html'], function($, _, Backbone, bus, html) {
var TravellerView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this);
        this.render();
    },
    template: _.template(html),
    render: function() {
        // code omitted..
        this.$el.html(this.template({
            slices: datesSliced, 
            segmentName: this.options.segmentName,
            currentDate: this.options.currentDate
        }));
        console.log('rendered at: ' + new Date().toString());
        return this;
    },
    events: {
        'click a.handle-prev': 'showPrevious',
        'click a.handle-next': 'showNext'
    },
    showNext: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        console.log('nothing happens');
    }
...
```

`Render()` gets called only once - at least in Chrome console there's only one message.

The corresponding *template* looks like this:

```
<ul><!-- things are omitted.. --></ul>
<a href="#" class="handle-prev"><i class="icon-chevron-left icon-3x"></i></a>
<a href="#" class="handle-next"><i class="icon-chevron-right icon-3x"></i></a>
```

The problem is that neither clicking on `<a class="handle-next">` nor triggering the event (`$('a.handle-next').trigger('click')`) manually fires `showNext` handler.

I've played either with `return false`, `stopPropagation()`, `preventDefault()`, `stopImmediatePropagation()` and even with setting up `javascript:void(0)` as *href* value.

How do I diagnose what is wrong? It is like event handlers are totally ignored or detached.

**EDIT. events hash**

I checked events hash of the view with help of

```
showEventsHash: function() {
    console.log(_.result(this, 'events'));
}
```

It isn't empty: in Chrome console one can see

[image]

Comment: Is 'html' your template markup?

Comment: I didn't understand you @kinakuta.

Comment: You're passing what I'm only assuming is the require dependency 'html' in to your template invocation. Since I can't see where html was defined, I'm just asking if html is the template markup that has presumably been selected elsehwere.

Comment: you could scroll right a little bit it's just a requirejs alias for `text!templates/traveller.html` resulting text.

Comment: why do you need `_.bindAll(this);` in `initialize` function?

Comment: Are you setting el when instantiating your TravellerView ? As in new TravellerView({ el: $("#something") });

Comment: @JonasGeiregat No. I use html template there's no need to do that.

Comment: Try setting el to a correct value. I'm not certain what happens if you don't set an el on your view.

Comment: Why are you adding the buttons to the template ? It feels to me that the only thing that needs to be in the template is the ul tags. You don't need to re-render the next and previous buttons each time, do you ? If so you can add an el to your view and if your buttons are contained by your el , event should work as expected.

Comment: I've written a simple test. View uses template with just one anchor tag. It works.

Comment: have You looked at what is in $el after rendering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At my router I found these lines:

```
var $content = $('#content-region');

var traveller = new TravellerView({
    // options
});

var $wrapper = $('<div></div>', { 'class': 'row-fluid' });
$wrapper.append(traveller.el);
$content.append($wrapper[0].outerHTML);
```

I changed my template markup to avoid this wrapping like that:

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <ul><!-- items --></ul>
    <a href="#" class="handle-prev"><!-- i tag --></a>
    <a href="#" class="handle-next"><!-- i tag --></a>
</div>
```

it worked.

Then I found similar piece:

```
var $row = $('<div />', {'class': 'row-fluid'});
for(var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
    $row.append(new PhotoCardView({
        model: this.collection.models[i]
    }).el);
}

this.$el.html($row[0].outerHTML);
return this;
```

**edit**

now I use this instead:

```
this.$el.append('<div class="row-fluid"></div>');

for(var i = startPos; i < endPos; i++) {
    this.$el.find('.row-fluid').append(new PhotoCardView({
        model: this.collection.models[i]
    }).el);
}
```

In the last case one can see that `el` objects are being appended to a dynamically created `$row` element. But when you call `outerHTML` your `el`-based events get stripped out.

Comment: `outerHTML` is a string and strings don't have event bindings.

Comment: @muistooshort Does $row object have event bindings? I think yes. What's the best way to wrap `el` saving its event bindings?

Comment: `$row` should be fine as the underlying DOM elements will have the event bindings. But then it falls apart when it gets `outerHTML`ed and converted to a string. I'm curious what the intent of this code is, some sort of cheap'n'dirty cloning perhaps?

Comment: Nothing special. i just wanted to wrap a list of child views into a grid row.

Comment: You don't need the wrappers, the view will create a `<div>` as its `el` by default and you can usually just throw your stuff in there, then the caller will `$(x).append(v.render().el)` for some `x`. You can use [`tagName`, `className`, ...](http://backbonejs.org/#View-el) properties on your view if you want something other than `<div>` as the `el`.